# visual studio not importing simple image in a non project file

Tags: html, image, visual-studio

I don't know what to do now there is no such folders in my laptop as in the error

as you can see this is the most basic type of image html, i do have the image downloaded in my laptop but still can't import it to this file if anyone could atleast tell me how to change import location for an image in vs community 2019 it will be very helpfull.

Comment: could you please ask a more specific question, providing a more detailed description? Like, when I do this this and this, I expect that that and that, but I get that and that, instead.

Comment: From what I can make out, your image is in HTML format, when it should have been a JPG, PNG, TIFF etc. You must have selected "save website" instead of "save image" in the right-click menu, that's why you cannot import it. Save it in an *actual* image format and try importing it into your solution's resources again.

Comment: I simply want to add a image to a html file i write in the img tag when i try to incode it (feature in vs 2019) it shows an error showing tht the image is does not exist in this folder (which in first place there is no such folder in my laptop)

Comment: no bro it is in jpg format the problem is i don't know from where these new folders are coming from when the image is stored separatly in other folder (tht exist)

Comment: You have to save the image to **the same folder** as the HTML file is in. Else it cannot find the file.

Comment: ok let me try that too

Comment: I'm going to post it as an answer. You should accept it to change the status of your question to solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save the image to **the same folder** as the HTML file is in. Else it cannot find the file.